# Odoo 10 crashes in macOS with error Python(2026,0x700003e4e000) malloc

Tags: odoo

After installation, this worked fine and after setting the master password, and when tried to load again in **localhost:8069**

I got the following error in console and python closed unexpectedly.

```
2017-01-14 05:08:01,154 2026 INFO Odoo odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_http: Generating routing map
Python(2026,0x700003e4e000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9aac016788: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
Jinn-MacBook-Air:odoo juasoft$
```

[image]

CONSOLE:

```
Jinn-MacBook-Air:odoo juasoft$ ./odoo-bin 
2017-01-15 14:57:21,427 3240 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0
2017-01-15 14:57:21,428 3240 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /Users/juasoft/.odoorc
2017-01-15 14:57:21,428 3240 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/Users/juasoft/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/10.0', u'/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/odoo/addons', u'/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/addons']
2017-01-15 14:57:21,428 3240 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default
2017-01-15 14:57:21,470 3240 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2017-01-15 14:57:26,646 3240 INFO ? odoo.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2017-01-15 14:57:27,053 3240 INFO ? odoo.addons.report.models.report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports.
2017-01-15 14:57:27,251 3240 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2017-01-15 14:57:27,264 3240 INFO juasoft odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2017-01-15 14:57:27,286 3240 INFO juasoft odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.02s, 0 queries
2017-01-15 14:57:27,299 3240 INFO juasoft odoo.modules.loading: loading 12 modules...
2017-01-15 14:57:27,326 3240 INFO juasoft odoo.modules.loading: 12 modules loaded in 0.03s, 0 queries
2017-01-15 14:57:27,458 3240 INFO juasoft odoo.modules.loading: Modules loaded.
2017-01-15 14:57:27,461 3240 INFO juasoft odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_http: Generating routing map
2017-01-15 14:57:27,584 3240 INFO juasoft werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:27] "GET /web/database/selector HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2017-01-15 14:57:27,640 3240 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:27] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/modal.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2017-01-15 14:57:27,640 3240 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:27] "GET /web/static/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2017-01-15 14:57:27,641 3240 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:27] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2017-01-15 14:57:27,641 3240 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:27] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2017-01-15 14:57:27,641 3240 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:27] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2017-01-15 14:57:27,642 3240 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:27] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2017-01-15 14:57:27,669 3240 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:27] "GET /web/static/src/img/logo2.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2017-01-15 14:57:33,501 3240 INFO juasoft werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:33] "GET /web?db=Odoo HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2017-01-15 14:57:33,516 3240 INFO ? odoo.http: Generating nondb routing
2017-01-15 14:57:33,529 3240 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:33] "GET /web?db=Odoo HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2017-01-15 14:57:33,549 3240 INFO Odoo odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2017-01-15 14:57:33,568 3240 INFO Odoo odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.02s, 0 queries
2017-01-15 14:57:33,616 3240 INFO Odoo odoo.modules.loading: loading 33 modules...
2017-01-15 14:57:33,787 3240 INFO Odoo odoo.modules.loading: 33 modules loaded in 0.17s, 0 queries
2017-01-15 14:57:34,262 3240 INFO Odoo odoo.modules.loading: Modules loaded.
2017-01-15 14:57:34,266 3240 INFO Odoo odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_http: Generating routing map
2017-01-15 14:57:34,304 3240 INFO Odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:34] "GET /web?db=Odoo HTTP/1.1" 303 -
Python(3240,0x70000132f000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9686f941a8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
Jinn-MacBook-Air:odoo juasoft$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an error with the C library. You should do some checkings with the Python Packages you've installed and reinstalling/updating/removing some might resolve the issue.

It could be reinstalling/updating Python itself as well.

If you dabbled into some high performance modules requiring C libraries and wrote some code, make sure you did not do this mistake https://stackoverflow.com/a/7210809/4832607 Have a nice day.

Comment: Odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2017 14:57:34] "GET /web?db=Odoo HTTP/1.1" 303 -

Comment: Can you create a new database ?